# Creating virtual drawing pad in visual studio using c++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I want to develop an application on windows platform that can simulate mouse events. I want to use webcam feed as an input to my application. I have knowledge of openCv libraries and c++ up to an extent.Out of console and windows forms applications which will be better choice?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet . I am searching for ways to creating an application with my available knowledge if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some kind of paraplegic person can use a pc application by just eye movement, blinkingToClick etc... take a look at this:
from

- open cv: http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/
- a project:
  http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/

Comment: This is an amazing answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input.I will check the links you mentioned